# get parent offsetX when child clicked

Tags: jquery

I have structure:

```
<div class="parent"> 
   <div class="child"> 
   </div>
<div>
```

I have jquery binded click

```
$('div.parent').bind('click', function(e) { e.offsetX });
```

chid is centered, when I click it, I have e.offsetX of child not parent.
How can I get parent offsetX, if clicking on child element?

### I want to always get parent e.offsetX

I mean event.click offset, not container offset

Comment: Are you sure you get the offsetX this way.

Comment: forgot 'click' before, yes I can get e.offsetX this way

Comment: so you get the click's offsetX on the parent. but you don't want to bind on child div. is it?

Comment: I want to always get parent click offsetX, but now I'm getting child offsetX

Comment: see the answer posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I grab the offsetX of the parent div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155812/how-do-i-grab-the-offsetx-of-the-parent-div)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var offset = $(this).closest("div").css("offsetX");
```

like this the var offset will have the value of the parents div offset.

UPDATE:

```
$("#something").click(function(e){
   var childOffset = $(this).offset();
   alert(e.pageX - e.childOffset);
});
```

By subtacting the child offset from the entire offset you get the parent offset.

Comment: I need click event.offsetX

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
$('div.parent').bind('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.offsetX); // gives the offsetX of the click not the parent div
});
```

`e.offsetX` denotes the ***`offsetX of the click`*** happened on parent div. I guess you want the `offsetX` of the dom node/jquery object which in case is parent div.

```
$('div.parent').on('click', function(e) { // use .on() instead
  alert($(e.target).offset().left); // $(e.target).offset().left will give you offsetX.
});
```

```js
$('div.parent').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('left : '+ $(e.target).offset().left + "top : "+$(e.target).offset().top);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: I ment parent event.click offset