# How do I grab the offsetX of the parent div?

Tags: javascript

Been struggling for a while on this so I decided to craft up a jsfiddle to show an example:

```
gameworld  = document.getElementById('GameWorld');
character  = document.getElementById('c');

gameworld.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    character.style.left=''+e.offsetX+'px';
    character.style.top=''+e.offsetY+'px';
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g43nxhcw/1/

If you click anywhere on the red container, you grab the `offsetX`, and `offsetY`. But, if you click on the tile, you grab **its** offset instead, which is causing the character to not move to that spot.

What I am trying to do is grab the `GameWorld's` `offsetX` and `offsetY` even if the tile is clicked upon, is that possible?

When looking at the console we can see that `e.target` shows which element the user has clicked on. This is about as close as I can get, because I need to find the offset's of the `GameWorld's` element when a parent child element of it, is clicked on.

I can get access to `GameWorld's` node when the `img` tile is clicked on, by accessing:

`e.path[0]`, as pertinent [here](http://i.gyazo.com/a13d11892e0632153113612fada0f4a7.png)

Sadly, that is where I get stuck and not sure what to grab with the node tree.

Edit: I don't want to use `pointer-events` either because It seems like its a easy way out of the problem, and for collision detection later, it will become an issue.

#### Edit2: **WARNING**

I was using `transform:translate(X,Y)` on these VALUES and they DO NOT get passed to the DOM (for offsets) so if anyone gets stuck on this, remember to add `top:` and `left:` properties for the dom to catch the offsets & values.

Comment: On offsetX/offsetY in FF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334452/event-offsetx-in-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the child’s `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` properties. For arbitrary depths (it seemed cleaner):

```
var offsetX = e.offsetX;
var offsetY = e.offsetY;

var element = e.target;

while (element !== gameworld) {
    offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
    offsetY += element.offsetTop;
    element = element.parentNode;
}

character.style.left = offsetX + 'px';
character.style.top = offsetY + 'px';
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g43nxhcw/3/)

Comment: Ha, been struggling with this for months and you post a solution in minutes. My God.  Will Mark in T-6min, thank you.

Comment: I just found out another problem.. I was using `transform: translate('+T[i].x+'px, '+T[i].y+'px);` to position the tiles and the `top`, and `left` properties weren't getting passed to the DOM.......  Haha no freaking wonder why I was having so many issues. Learned my damn lesson though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if this is still buggy, you can substract `target.offsetWidth/2` or `target.offsetHeight/2` depending on the context. (because `offsetLeft` is calculated from the center of the current element.)